# Python 'startswith' equivalent for SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a string, for which I need to find all records with matching prefixs:

```
path = '/abc/123/456'
session.query(Site).filter(path.startswith(Site.path_prefix))
```

The following records would match when path_prefix equals:

```
/abc
/ab
/abc/123
```

But not:

```
/asd
/abc/123/456/789
/kjk
```

Is this possible with SqlAlchemy, without switching over to python?

Comment: Do you mean `Site.path_prefix in path`? Also, in pure Python semantic this will match strings like `23/4` and the empty string too, is that what you want?

Comment: @KennyTM, thanks for the correction. I want prefixes only.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you wrap the `path` variable in a [`bindparam()` object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) then you can treat it like any column, including using the [`.contains()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.contains) and [`.startswith()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.startswith) operators:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam

session.query(Site).filter(bindparam('path', path).contains(Site.path_prefix))
```

SQLAlchemy translates `.contains()` to:

```
? LIKE CONCAT('%', Site.path_prefix, '%')
```

on MySQL or

```
? LIKE '%' || Site.path_prefix || '%'
```

on other databases.

If you wanted to test for a `.startswith()` operation instead, that works too:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam

session.query(Site).filter(bindparam('path', path).startswith(Site.path_prefix))
```

Comment: I was thinking `startswith(path, Site.path_prefix)` (as path_prefix, path) was exactly the trap we fell in to wasn't it?

Comment: @JonClements: Sure, but that's not the same as `in`. I've added the option already; just remove the first `%` wildcard. SQLAlchemy does offer a `startswith()` but only for columns, since this is the inverse we need to do the `LIKE` construction ourselves.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Is there an alternative to concat that works with sqlite? It seems like concat isn't supported there: OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such function: concat u'SELECT...

Comment: @Ramin: Ah, my mistake, the `functions.concat()` was overkill. It's sufficient to use `+` string concatenation, it'll be translated correctly for different databases.

Comment: @Ramin: Actually, since the central premise is to use a `bindparam()`, the SQLAlchemy `.startswith()` and `.contains()` operators also work.