# Reverse version of sql LIKE in sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, sql-like

By "reverse version of like" I mean exactly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472063/mysql-what-is-a-reverse-version-of-like). The question is how to make a query like that in sqlalchemy?

I found out that to make "SELECT LIKE" query in sqlalchemy I should make something like that

```
session.query(Book).filter(Book.title.like("%"+my_title+"%"))
```

Because `like` is method of column, I don't know how to use `like` method to ask about `"%" + Book.title + "%"`.

Comment: @Spudley That question is about a NOT LIKE operator, this question is about reversing the relationship between the column and the pattern.

Comment: So if `Book.title` contains "blah" you want the query to succeed when `my_title` contains "Something with blah in it", right?

Comment: @Spudley: this is not a duplicate of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176252/python-startswith-equivalent-for-sqlalchemy) question, I figure out how to do that :)

```
session.query(Book).
    filter(bindparam('book_title', book.title).contains(Book.title)).first()
```

Comment: `literal(book.title)` is a shortcut for that bindparam()

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for exactly this. Both the bindparam() and literal() approach works. Can you please explain what is happening under the hood which makes this approach work? Thanks!