# Sqlachemy ORM query like in reverse

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have table name `VenueSetting`

```
id  prefix  type
------------------
1   456     1
2   8       2
3   4560    3
```

how to query on a input number to get matched the **prefix** in database using **SqlAchemy ORM query**, a version of `like` in reverse

something like this query

```
from_phone = '456789000'
session.query(VenueSetting).
         filter(from_phone.like(VenueSetting.prefix + '%')).
         first()

#expect result is record with id=1 in database
```

Comment: It seems you have the same question with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176252/python-startswith-equivalent-for-sqlalchemy